# How can you translate mouse drag to rotation about a 3D object in vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, geometry, html5-canvas

What I am trying to do is turn mouse drag (x,y) along the screen into full rotation for a 3D object (in this example, a sphere)
(as of writing this there is no option for me to include a stack snippet so I will link a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dfgyua28/) and include some example code in a block)

```
// Handle click
canvas.onmousedown = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  let pos1 = e.pageX
  let pos2 = e.pageY
  if (e.button == 0) {
    document.onmousemove = (e) => {
      canvas.style.cursor = 'grabbing'
      let pos3 = pos1 - e.pageX
      let pos4 = pos2 - e.pageY
      for (let i = 0; i < Spheres.length; i++) {
        Spheres[i].move_centre(-pos3 / scale,-pos4 / scale)
      }
      pos1 = e.pageX
      pos2 = e.pageY
    }
  } else if (e.button == 2) {
    document.onmousemove = (e) => {
      canvas.style.cursor = 'grabbing'
      let pos3 = pos1 - e.pageX
      let pos4 = pos2 - e.pageY
      let delta = vector(pos3, pos4, 0)
      let angle = sqrt(pos3**2 + pos4**2) * (PI / 180)
      let rotaxis = vector.normalize(vector.cross(vector(0,0,-1), delta))
      let axisangle = vector(rotaxis.x * angle, rotaxis.y * angle, rotaxis.z * angle)
      for (let i = 0; i < Spheres.length; i++) {
        let circumference = (2 * Spheres[i].Radius) * PI
        let o = vector.mul(vector(Spheres[i].gamma, Spheres[i].phi, Spheres[i].theta), axisangle)
        Spheres[i].gamma += o.x
        Spheres[i].phi += o.y
        Spheres[i].theta += o.z
        //Spheres[i].gamma += -(pos3 / circumference) /  scale * 2
        //Spheres[i].phi += (pos4 / circumference) / scale * 2
        //Spheres[i].theta += (deltaz/scale) / circumference / 100
      }
      pos1 = e.pageX
      pos2 = e.pageY
    }
  }
  
  document.onmouseup = (e) => {
    document.onmousemove = null
    canvas.style.cursor = 'auto'
  }
}
```

I used this [page](https://artrointel.github.io/rotating-objects/) to get a general idea of how it is done but in the example I was not able to reproduce the same outcome as it described. I do not understand whether I followed the instructions wrong, if I incorrectly assumed something or any other problem.

Comment: See [Mouse Trackball](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Object_Mouse_Trackball)